# How to exctract a single link in a webpage using PHP?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, scrape

I'm looking for a solution to extract only one URL from a specific webpage using PHP.

### Here's a simple example of what I need:

1. I have a URL with many links (https://apkpure.com/mi-home/com.xiaomi.smarthome/download?from=details)
2. I want to scrape the link under the anchor `click here` from the current page.
3. Then the code must return this result `https://download.apkpure.com/b/XAPK/Y29tLnhpYW9taS5zbWFydGhvbWVfNjMwNjdfYWU1M2FmOWU?_fn=TWkgSG9tZV92NS44LjdfYXBrcHVyZS5jb20ueGFwaw&as=4c5e64f6f957edac834f3631fe4e09715f2e35f6&ai=-1070628217&at=1596863870&_sa=ai%2Cat&k=24cb20f95fbf333deb01c145ce7b982b5f30d87e&_p=Y29tLnhpYW9taS5zbWFydGhvbWU&c=1%7CLIFESTYLE%7CZGV2PVhpYW9taSUyMEluYy4mdD14YXBrJnM9MTI5OTAzMTM4JnZuPTUuOC43JnZjPTYzMDY3`.

### I tried this:

```
$sourceURL="https://apkpure.com/mi-home/com.xiaomi.smarthome/download?from=details";
$htmlSource=htmlentities(file_get_contents($sourceURL));

echo strip_tags($htmlSource, "<a>");
```

**I get the result with all links including the one I need**

I need your help to extract the `href value` of the link I want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most elegant way is to use a DOM parser.

- Iterate thru anchors
- Check if anchor ID is 'download_link' (which is in the 'click here' link)
- Extract the href attribute value

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://apkpure.com/mi-home/com.xiaomi.smarthome/download?from=details');

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$href = '';
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $item) {
    if($item->getAttribute('id') == 'download_link') {
        $href = $item->getAttribute('href');
        break;
    }
}

echo $href;
```

> https://download.apkpure.com/b/XAPK/Y29tLnhpYW9taS5zbWFydGhvbWVfNjMwNjdfYWU1M2FmOWU?_fn=TWkgSG9tZV92NS44LjdfYXBrcHVyZS5jb20ueGFwaw&as=6a7de2cb660007a32e4b3d61a0d3c41e5f2e7102&ai=1946881098&at=1596878986&_sa=ai%2Cat&k=9e912b1007d50d2be9af8e78bcdea86c5f31138a&_p=Y29tLnhpYW9taS5zbWFydGhvbWU&c=1%7CLIFESTYLE%7CZGV2PVhpYW9taSUyMEluYy4mdD14YXBrJnM9MTI5OTAzMTM4JnZuPTUuOC43JnZjPTYzMDY3

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It did exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the required URL, you can see it has a pattern `https://download.apkpure.com` at start of each `Click Here URL`, so, we can use regex to find it.

`preg_match_all` will return an array of strings that will match our regex. Then I have used implode to convert the first index to a string.

Here is the complete working code:

```
$sourceURL="https://apkpure.com/mi-home/com.xiaomi.smarthome/download?from=details";
$content=file_get_contents($sourceURL);
$content = strip_tags($content,"<a>");
preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://download.apkpure.com[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $content, $match);
echo implode(', ', $match[0]);
```